# gulp watch .js file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload      = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('serve')

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./public"
    });

    gulp.watch('./public/**/*.html').on('change', reload); // worked
    gulp.watch('./public/**/*.js').on('change', reload); // doesn't work
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./public/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./public/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve','sass', 'sass:watch']);
```

With above gulp setup, my broswersnyc works fine when I make changes to my html and sass files but it doesn't work for javascript files.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Does it have to do with AngularJS? Because my `app.js` (which is within my `public` folder) consists of AngularJS controllers.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your screenshot your `app.js` is not in your `public` folder.

Comment: Remove public everywhere in gulpfile

Answer (score 3):

If you move your app.js to "public/js" folder it will work fine

```
gulp.watch('./public/**/*.js').on('change', reload); // doesn't work
```

because in the pervious snippet you're watching the js files in the child folders of the public dir.

you might use this line instead, it might work

```
gulp.watch(['./public/**/*.js', './public/*.js']).on('change', reload);
```